# jQuery AJAX submitting not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm having trouble with a jquery ajax submit form. Here's the jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(function() {
        $(".submit").click(function() {
            var number = $("#number").val();
            var machine_id = $("#machine_id").val();
            var dataString = 'number='+ number + '&machine_id=' + machine_id;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://www.onmsgmedia.com/hurryitUP/updatetextdatabase.php",
                data: dataString,
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

and here is the form code:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" id="machine_id" name="machine_id" value="5">
    <input type="text" id="number" name="number"></input>
    <input class="btn btn-small btn-success" type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</input>
</form>
```

And the code of updatetextdatabase.php:

```
    <?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');//set time zone
$con=mysqli_connect('saslaundry.db.10410357.hostedresource.com', 'saslaundry', 'password', 'saslaundry');//establish connection
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())//ping database to check connection
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();//error message
  }
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO textrequests VALUES('$_GET[number]', '$_GET[machine_id]') ");
    return;
?>
```

But not only is it not submitting the form, the page also reloads, which is sort of what I was trying to avoid by using AJAX. I feel like the problem is that the function is not being called by the submit button, but I can't figure out why.

Thanks!

Comment: Change the method to GET, and show me the code of updatetextdatabase.php pls!

Comment: you are missing the closing `)` of ajax is a typo mistake ?

Comment: @RobertRozas: Changing it to GET didn't work. I added the code of updatetextdatabase.php.

Comment: @dianuj: The closing ) is after return false; I believe.

Comment: @dianuj is correct. You're missing the closing `)`.  You need to close the ajax function before returning 0.  Your page is reloading because of a javascript error caused by the missing parenthesis.

Comment: @LukeBaumann buddy you have opened ` $.ajax({` but closed with `}` where is the closing `)` ? other `});` these are the closing of ready and click function but not for ajax

Comment: Thanks @dianuj, I added the closing ) but for some reason its still not working. Though I do see why I needed that.

Answer (score 1):

try this one use `e.preventDefault();`  prevent your form  to submit and then perform your `ajax` call

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(function() {
        $(".submit").click(function() {
            e.preventDefault();
            var number = $("#number").val();
            var machine_id = $("#machine_id").val();
            var dataString = 'number='+ number + '&machine_id=' + machine_id;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://www.onmsgmedia.com/hurryitUP/updatetextdatabase.php",
                data: dataString,
               success: function (data) {
                //do something here when you got the response
             }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

[**event.preventDefault**](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: Still no luck. I definitely think that the submit button is not calling the method, because even when I put in an alert in the function to test it the alert didn't show. Do you have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Please check your console panel for javascript errors in the browser and make sure you have included the jquery

Comment: Hi,I had a few javascript errors but none of them were directly related as far as I could tell... I fixed them all anyway.  and I did include Jquery from the google api.

Comment: By the way, the script is in the <head>. Is this ok?

Answer (score 1):

I made this working fiddle:

HTML:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="">
<input type="hidden" id="machine_id" name="machine_id" value="5" />
    <input type="text" id="number" name="number" />
    <input class="btn btn-small btn-success" type="button" class="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").click(function() {
        var number = $("#number").val();
        var machine_id = $("#machine_id").val();
        var dataString = 'number='+ number + '&machine_id=' + machine_id;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://www.onmsgmedia.com/hurryitUP/updatetextdatabase.php",
            data: dataString

    });
});
});
```

Network Console:

```
Request URL:http://www.onmsgmedia.com/hurryitUP/updatetextdatabase.php
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Origin:http://fiddle.jshell.net
Referer:http://fiddle.jshell.net/WJGhr/show/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)    Chrome/29.0.1547.66 Safari/537.36
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
number:25
machine_id:5
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WJGhr/

Comment: Thanks so much!!! This works really well. The only one problem is that it seems to pass values of 0 for the variables. It's really weird. The datastring has the correct variables, but then when it submits to the database it inputs 0 for both variables. But i'll figure that part out.

Comment: In your php script put something like this var_dump($_GET[number]); and see what it prints in the network console.